# Is it possible for $x^2=a \pmod p$ and $x^2=b \pmod p$ do not have solutions, but $x^2=ab \pmod p$ has a solution.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Is this possible? Examples are appreciated

Comment: There is no solution to $x^2\equiv2\pmod 5$ or $x^2\equiv3\pmod 5$, but there is a solution to $x^2\equiv6\pmod 5$.  The term you want to Google is "quadratic residue".

Comment: Are you asking  for a proof of that property?  The usual argument is to count the squares.  There are exactly $\frac {p-1}2$ squares hence the same number of non-squares.  Now remark that a non-square times a square can not be a square.

Comment: Yeah I need a proof for this argument. I'm just trying to work through examples in my textbook for review but theres no answer key and I can't find videos so I'm struggling to teach myself.

Comment: wouldn't these be two nonsquares multiplied?

Comment: Yes, but you need the non-square times square case for counting.

Comment: Do you know [Euler's Criterion?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). If not, you should (assuming you haven't yet met the Legendre symbol).

Comment: What would be sufficient to show there is no solution to $^2$≡2(mod5) has no solution.

Comment: I have shown 0$^2$= 0(Mod 5), 1$^2$= 1(Mod 5), 2$^2$= 4(Mod 5),3$^2$= 4(Mod 5), 4$^2$= 1(Mod 5) but would I keep needing to test every number?

Comment: What is the rule behind why this has no solution?

Comment: Use `\pmod` for the parenthetical verion) and `\bmod` for the binary operator. Do not use `\mod`, because it gives the wrong spacing.

Comment: If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solutions, but $x^2\equiv (-1)(-1)\pmod{p}$ definitely does.

Answer (score 5):

We start by noting that, since the integers $\pmod p$ form a field, and since $p$ is odd,  then there are exactly $\frac {p-1}2$ non-zero squares $\pmod p$.   Hence there are the same number of non-zero non-squares.

Let $N$ denote a non-zero non-square $\pmod p$ .  If we let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}$ run through the non-zero residues we remark that each of the products $N\times a_i$ must be distinct $\pmod p$.  If $a_1$, say, is a square then $N\times a_1$ can not also be a square since in that case we'd have $N\times a^2\equiv b^2\implies N\equiv \left(ba^{-1}\right)^2$.  Since there are $\frac {p-1}2$ squares we get all the $\frac {p-1}2$ non-squares as $N\times a^2$ for some $a$.  If $N'$ is a non-square (possibly equal to $N$) Then $N\times N'$ can not be a non-square, since all the non-squares are accounted for. Hence it must be a square, and we are done.

Comment: This is the only actual answer here so far, imo.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)? If $x^2\equiv a \pmod p$ for some $x$ we write $\Big({a\over p}\Big)=1$ else it is $-1$. There is a theorem $$\Big({a\over p}\Big)\Big({b\over p}\Big) =\Big({ab\over p}\Big) $$
and thus a conclusion.

Comment: No I'm not familiar. If there is a solution it is =1 if it has no solution it is =-1?

Comment: -1*-1=1? Can I substitute values for the fractions?